# Compare two XML strings with same node and attributes and update the value of old string with new string

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have 2 xml strings with same attributes as below:

```
<root result="1" lvalue="2"/>
```

and the new xml string is

```
<root result="1" lvalue="3"/>
```

How to update the old xml string with new one?

I basically get the new one as a request to update the old one as a parameter in method where I have to update the old xml string after comparing both of them.

Thank you.

Comment: Those `,` characters are not valid XML.  Presumably these strings are part of a larger XML document?  What are you having issues with?

Comment: Use the XElement method SetElementValue() or XAttribute method SetAttributeValue()

Comment: @AlexK. I updated the xml value to the right one, it does not have any separator between the attributes. My actual xml has 50 attirbutes with one single node like above, so my new xml has only one value to be changed in all the 50 attributes, i am trying to compare two xml strings by using linq to xml. looking for a neat way to find that one element and update.

Comment: Parse them both `var oldxml = XElement.Parse("<root blabla></root>"); newxml = ...` (note the closing tag) then you can simply `oldxml.Attribute("result").Value = newxml.Attribute("result").Value;`